# take order even out of stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on [this](http://toolskaart.com)

website. In that one the customer must be made to give orders even it is out of stock. The delivery will be delayed a bit. Please help me. I'm new to this magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable that under System > Configuration. There you go to Catalog > Inventory and set Backorders to `Alw Qty below 0`

Comment: but this will enable for all customers

Comment: @S-Buzz: I tried what you said. But it didn't work out. Please have a look at it http://toolskaart.com/index.php/boring-tools/sclcl-r/s06f-sclcl-04-f3.html. I even added an extension to show that the item is out of stock.